# How to remove Joist finder screw of Squeeeeek-No-More-Floor-Repair-Kit using jaw locking pliers

Tags: removal

As I was inserting a joist finder screw in carpeted floor, a component of the Squeeeeek-No-More-Floor-Repair-Kit, it got stuck in the floor so tightly that it couldn't be removed with a power drill no matter how much pressure I applied. You can see in the picture below that about half the length of the screw is stuck in the carpeted floor.

So I purchased locking jaw pliers from Walmart but maybe because the screw is very thin they do not close firmly so when I rotate them to remove the screws they detach.

Can anyone recommend any videos or other resources or methods I can use for help with removing the joist finder screw using either jaw locking pliers or a power drill as these are the only tools I have? None of the Youtube videos I watched or articles I read have addressed this issue specifically (or for some reason the jaw locking pliers did not stay attached to the screw once they closed as shown).

[image: Locking pliers]

Comment: It's always a good idea to include pictures so we can give accurate advise. If you can, please add one of the screw as it is now and maybe another with the pliers clamped and unclamped to the screw.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you sure you tightened the pliers (with the bolt in the handle) **before** you clamped it on? You should be able to get a whole lot of force on that screw. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: have you tired putting the vise-grips on the shaft, as close-as-possible to the floor? (instead of on the head?). The vise-grips should be very easily adjusted to grip so tight that the screw must turn.

Comment: It looks like you now have [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/108698/user402525) separate [accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/108678/andrew); you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.